# magento add new column to database changes in files

Tags: magento

I want to add new column to the existing sales_flat_order table of magento.

The column name is verified_in this column is a varchar 32 .
Do i need to add this column name some where in the magento code?

If so please let me know.

Im using magento 1.5.1 version with mysql5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add new columns to an existing table, create a custom module and in it's setup script add the required code to add your column. You may find a good start here: http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources

Answer (score 0):

A little late but this blog ciovers adding a column to the salse_flat_order table: http://www.blessthemoon.com/despatch-date-module-part-4-setting-up-the-database/.

Hope useful to someone.